# How to pass a function as a prop to React function component?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Im trying to pass a function down as a prop. Why is this not working?

In Parent:

```
const dummyProps = {
    label: "Text",
    increment: function() {
        console.log("+");
    },
};

function Parent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Child {...dummyProps} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

In Child:

```
function InputNumeric({ label, increment }) {
    return(
        <label>{label}</label>
        <button onClick={increment}>Click</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: It should work. Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: What does `not working` mean? Is an exception thrown? [**This code should work fine**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-tnb5d). You need to put a `Fragment` around the child elements though, is that your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The actually problem was I was testing in Storybook. When I check in my app it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React, you need to have a single parent element that is rendered. In your question you forgot to wrap the elements inside the child component. You can wrap with another element or with a `React.Fragment` (shorthand syntax is `<> </>`)

```
function InputNumeric({ label, increment }) {
    return(
        <>
          <label>{label}</label>
          <button onClick={increment}>Click</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Remember,

```
<div prop1={'asdf'}></div>
```

is actually translated to

```
React.createElement('div', {prop1: 'asdf'})
```

Comment: Technically you can also return an array without the use of fragments. But in that case you'll need to add the `key` props to all the elements in the array.